# CPQ - show/hide global header

Tags: cpq

We are working with cpq in lightning experience. The global salesforce header is usually on when clicking edit lines in quote. However, when I redirect to this page using the VF page style apex/sbqq__sb?id=[quoteId]. The page displays correctly but the global header is missing on that page. I checked the page code but haven't quite figured out. Is that something I can fix via changing some configure settings?

Answer (score 0):

When you click the Edit Lines button on a quote, the button is configured to "Display in existing window without sidebar". If you are launching the page from a button, make sure you have the same option selected.

If you are redirecting there from code, I'm not sure what the solution is. There is some logic in the sbqq__sb page to show a header:

`showHeader="{!(!$Setup.SBQQ__GeneralSettings__c.SBQQ__GlobalHeaderPermUsed__c || !$Permission.SBQQ__HideGlobalHeader) && formFactor == 'desktop'}"`

I tried changing the setting "Use Global Header Permission" in CPQ settings, but it didn't have any impact.